# Combining consecutive rows based on a "type" column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, etl

I am looking for ideas and solutions T-SQL to combine consecutive records like the example below.

The source database I'm working with will have audit records, and a column called "Audit_Type" which could contain many different things such as "Saved Form" "Exported Record", "Imported Record", or "Viewed Record" etc. This database ends up with a bunch of extraneous records for the "Saved Form" type, because the app that makes this database autosaves forms as a user edits it fairly regularly. So often there will be a bunch of "Saved Form" records in a row.
To picture it:

```
ID     Audit Type        DateTime
1   "Viewed Record"   2017-01-03 11:16:33.000
2   "Saved Form"      2017-01-04 09:51:36.837
3   "Saved Form"      2017-01-04 09:52:40.837
4   "Saved Form"      2017-01-04 09:52:44.837
5   "Saved Form"      2017-01-04 09:52:49.837
6   "Saved Form"      2017-01-04 09:52:54.837
7   "Saved Form"      2017-01-04 09:54:59.837
8   "Exported Record" 2017-01-04 09:55:59.837
```

**Question 1.** I would like to combine these consecutive "Saved Form" records into one record, by grabbing consecutive "Saved Form" records and combining them into one record that uses the timestamp of the very last "Saved Form"  before loading it into my target database. Something like this

```
ID     Audit Type        DateTime
1   "Viewed Record"   2017-01-03 11:16:33.000
7   "Saved Form"      2017-01-04 09:54:59.837
8   "Exported Record" 2017-01-04 09:55:59.837
```

I have tried a few approaches so far but I would like to hear ideas.

**Question 2.** Based on my research and reading other similar questions on SO, I saw this could be similar to an Islands and Gaps problem, is this an accurate characterization of this problem?

EDIT
This is for SQL Server 2012.
I'm extracting from a database that I have no control over how it logs the information.

Also to clarify, there are other columns from this log table, I ommitted for brevity, so in the example above, we can assume all of the "Saved Form" records are from the same session and same user

Comment: which version of sql server?

Comment: What you need is to get your logging feature to include some kind of session key in the table that you could use with a group by expression.

Comment: @scsimon SQL server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gordon beat me to the answer. Yes, this does fit into an Islands and Gaps methodology. I think a LEAD() would suit this issue quite well. But I also tried a second query with a ROW_NUMBER(), which produced a slightly shorter execution plan. Not sure which would be more efficient at scale. That would require a bit more testing.

**NOTE 1:** I also added an assumed SessionID and UserID to my query. The additional columns may change your final results.

**NOTE 2:** SQL Fiddle reports that the ROW_NUMBER version runs much faster with fewer "same time" entries, but LEAD version is faster with many "same time" entries.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7d197e/2)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( ID int IDENTITY, sessionID int, userid int, AuditType varchar(50), [DateTime] datetime ) ;
INSERT INTO foo ( sessionID, userID, AuditType, [DateTime] )
VALUES 
      (1,1,'Viewed Record','2017-01-03 11:16:33.000')
    , (1,1,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 09:51:36.837')
    , (2,2,'Viewed Record','2017-01-04 09:52:00.000')
    , (1,1,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 09:52:40.837')
    , (1,1,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 09:52:44.837')
    , (2,2,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 09:52:45.000')
    , (2,2,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 09:52:46.000')
    , (2,2,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 09:52:47.000')
    , (2,2,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 09:52:48.000')
    , (1,1,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 09:52:49.837')
    , (1,1,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 09:52:54.837')
    , (2,2,'Exported Record','2017-01-04 09:53:00.000')
    , (1,1,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 09:54:59.837')
    , (1,1,'Exported Record','2017-01-04 09:55:59.837')
    , (2,1,'Viewed Record','2017-01-04 10:00:00.000')
    , (2,1,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 10:02:00.000')
    , (2,1,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 10:04:00.000')
    , (2,1,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 10:06:00.000')
    , (2,1,'Exported Record','2017-01-04 10:10:00.000')
;
```

**Query 1 (LEAD())**:

```
SELECT s1.sessionID
  , s1.userID
  , s1.AuditType
  , s1.[DateTime]
FROM (
    SELECT foo.*
      , LEAD(foo.AuditType) OVER ( ORDER BY foo.userID, foo.sessionID, foo.[DateTime] ) AS next_type
    FROM foo
  ) s1
WHERE s1.next_type IS NULL OR s1.next_type <> s1.AuditType
ORDER BY s1.sessionID, s1.userID, s1.[DateTime]
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7d197e/2/0)**:

```
| sessionID | userID |       AuditType |                 DateTime |
|-----------|--------|-----------------|--------------------------|
|         1 |      1 |   Viewed Record |     2017-01-03T11:16:33Z |
|         1 |      1 |      Saved Form | 2017-01-04T09:54:59.837Z |
|         1 |      1 | Exported Record | 2017-01-04T09:55:59.837Z |
|         2 |      1 |   Viewed Record |     2017-01-04T10:00:00Z |
|         2 |      1 |      Saved Form |     2017-01-04T10:06:00Z |
|         2 |      1 | Exported Record |     2017-01-04T10:10:00Z |
|         2 |      2 |   Viewed Record |     2017-01-04T09:52:00Z |
|         2 |      2 |      Saved Form |     2017-01-04T09:52:48Z |
|         2 |      2 | Exported Record |     2017-01-04T09:53:00Z |
```

**Query 2 (ROW_NUMBER())**:

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM (
    SELECT foo.*
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY foo.userID, foo.sessionID, foo.AuditType ORDER BY foo.userID, foo.sessionID, foo.[DateTime] DESC ) AS rn
    FROM foo
  ) s1
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY s1.sessionID, s1.userID, s1.[DateTime]
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7d197e/2/1)**:

```
| ID | sessionID | userid |       AuditType |                 DateTime | rn |
|----|-----------|--------|-----------------|--------------------------|----|
|  1 |         1 |      1 |   Viewed Record |     2017-01-03T11:16:33Z |  1 |
| 13 |         1 |      1 |      Saved Form | 2017-01-04T09:54:59.837Z |  1 |
| 14 |         1 |      1 | Exported Record | 2017-01-04T09:55:59.837Z |  1 |
| 15 |         2 |      1 |   Viewed Record |     2017-01-04T10:00:00Z |  1 |
| 18 |         2 |      1 |      Saved Form |     2017-01-04T10:06:00Z |  1 |
| 19 |         2 |      1 | Exported Record |     2017-01-04T10:10:00Z |  1 |
|  3 |         2 |      2 |   Viewed Record |     2017-01-04T09:52:00Z |  1 |
|  9 |         2 |      2 |      Saved Form |     2017-01-04T09:52:48Z |  1 |
| 12 |         2 |      2 | Exported Record |     2017-01-04T09:53:00Z |  1 |
```

They should both show:

```
  1,1,'Viewed Record','2017-01-03 11:16:33.000'
  1,1,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 09:54:59.837'
  1,1,'Exported Record','2017-01-04 09:55:59.837'

  2,1,'Viewed Record','2017-01-04 10:00:00.000'
  2,1,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 10:06:00.000'
  2,1,'Exported Record','2017-01-04 10:10:00.000'

  2,2,'Viewed Record','2017-01-04 09:52:00.000'
  2,2,'Saved Form','2017-01-04 09:52:48.000'
  2,2,'Exported Record','2017-01-04 09:53:00.000'
```

Comment: I just read your comment. I added extra rows into the schema with the same Saved Form times. I'm not seeing the duplication, but I also changed the above queries to group by SessionID and UserID. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6a005/1

Comment: With the data I am working with the Row Number solution performs much much better, I am still having trouble getting the exact results I want, but your answer has been very helpful.. It seems to be trimming my results down too far, it seems to be preventing consecutive rows of other audit types as well, I'm still adjusting the query to solve this secondary issue, but I would say for sure that in a dataset with a large number of records the row_Number works much better than the lead() method

Comment: Did you not need it to trim other types?

Comment: Change `WHERE rn = 1` to `WHERE rn = 1  AND s1.AuditType = 'Saved Form'`. That will only eliminate the `Saved Form` extra rows.

Comment: Yes, I only need to trim the saved form types, I should have been more clear about that. But I worked with it a bit and I think I'm basically getting what I want now using your Query 2 as a basis, I'm going to leave the question open until later tonight in case if there is more helpful input that may come from it, but I am going to give you the answer and close it at that point, thank you for your very helpful answer

Comment: Correction: Change that to `WHERE rn=1 OR s1.AuditType <> 'Saved Form'`.

Answer (score 1):

For your example data, you can simply do:

```
select type, max(id) as id, max(datetime) as datetime
from t
group by type;
```

You would only need a gap-and-islands solution if you had interleaved types.  That is, the same type appearing in two different groups.

In your case, you are only looking for the last record before it changes.  You can get that using `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(type) over (order by datetime) as next_type
      from t
     ) t
where next_type is null or next_type <> type;
```

This is simpler than most gap-and-islands problems.

To handle session/user, you would include the appropriate columns in the `group by` or partitioning clause of the `lead()`.

Comment: what happens when the next record is a View Record?

Comment: @scsimon . . . I'm not convinced that the OP really needs to deal with that.  In any case, this is could be an example of a simple gap-and-islands problem.

Comment: This is close but with the way I am using it right now, it seems to leave a few consecutive "Saved Form" rows in cases where there was a very large number of saves in a row, ie 20 saves in a row, my version of this lead query ends up condensing that down to 3, not one

Comment: @MidwestProgrammingDJ . . . The `lead()` version doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: It worked but the Row_Number solution performed better by a large margin on the dataset I am working with

Comment: @MidwestProgrammingDJ . . . (1) That surprises me.  (2) The `row_number()` solution is not the same;  if the audit types are interleaved, it returns each one only once.

Comment: If you read the comments on the above answer you can see that was addressed by adjusting the where clause which does in fact result in the same solution. I'm talking about double the query time for the dataset I'm working on which is around 1million records. 

Also, why do you start your comments with '. . .' I'm not sure what you are trying to convey with that but it comes off as condescending